# TypeError: string indices must be integers when using itemgetter with string argument

Tags: python, sorting, ifc

I am trying to achieve categorisation of an IFC model using IfcOpenShell.

In the first step I extract the the attributes `GlobalId`  and `ObjectType` from a list of IFC model elements. Then I would like to sort the information using the `ObjectType` attribute, to receive the following information from the model:

```
Basiswand:Bestand 08.0:161894
    {'GlobalId': '3vpWoB_K1EZ8RCaYmNGs6M', 'Element': 'Basiswand:Bestand 08.0:161894'}
    {'GlobalId': '3vpWoB_K1EZ8RCaYmNGsB2', 'Element': 'Basiswand:Bestand 08.0:161894'}
Fenster 1-flg - Variabel
    {'GlobalId': '3vpWoB_K1EZ8RCaYmNGssv', 'Element': 'Fenster 1-flg - Variabel'}
    {'GlobalId': '3vpWoB_K1EZ8RCaYmNGsqI', 'Element': 'Fenster 1-flg - Variabel'}
```

The elements with same `ObjectType` and with different `GlobalId` should be combined in one group, to get a categorisation.

```
rows =[]   
buildingelement = model.by_type('IfcBuildingElement')
for buildingelement in model.by_type('IfcBuildingElement'):
    rows.append(str(buildingelement.GlobalId) + ': ' + str(buildingelement.ObjectType))

print(rows)


from operator import itemgetter 
from itertools import groupby
    # Sort by the desired field first
rows.sort(key=itemgetter('IfcBuildingElement'))
    # Iterate in groups
for date, items in groupby(rows, key=itemgetter('IfcBuildingElement')): 
    print(date)
    for i in items: 
        print(' ', i)
```

With above code, I get the error message `Exception has occurred: TypeError string indices must be integers`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first loop, you collect the elements of `rows` as strings in the form `'3vpWoB...: Basiswand...'`. For example:

```
['3vpWoB_K1EZ8RCaYmNGs6M: Basiswand:Bestand 08.0:161894',
 '3vpWoB_K1EZ8RCaYmNGsB2: Basiswand:Bestand 08.0:161894',
 '3vpWoB_K1EZ8RCaYmNGssv: Fenster 1-flg - Variabel',
 '3vpWoB_K1EZ8RCaYmNGsqI: Fenster 1-flg - Variabel'
]
```

Then, when you sort and group with `itemgetter` as key function, you would have to specify a position or range in the string. E.g. when you want to compare based on the 24th character use `itemgetter(24)` or likewise to compare based on the trailing substring use `itemgetter(slice(24,-1))`.

```
>>> '3vpWoB_K1EZ8RCaYmNGs6M: Basiswand:Bestand 08.0:161894'[24]
'B'
>>> '3vpWoB_K1EZ8RCaYmNGs6M: Basiswand:Bestand 08.0:161894'[24:-1]
'Basiswand:Bestand 08.0:161894'
```

If you try to use a string as index to get a substring, like in `itemgetter('IfcBuildingElement')` you get the error you see.

```
>>> '3vpWoB_K1EZ8RCaYmNGs6M: Basiswand:Bestand 08.0:161894'['IfcBuildingElement']
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

So in order to successfully use `itemgetter('Element')` as key for sorting and grouping, you want to collect the rows as dictionaries of the form
`{'GlobalId': '3vpWoB...', 'Element': 'Basiswand...'}` instead of strings. For example:

```
[{'GlobalId':'3vpWoB_K1EZ8RCaYmNGs6M', 'Element':'Basiswand:Bestand 08.0:161894'},
 {'GlobalId':'3vpWoB_K1EZ8RCaYmNGsB2', 'Element':'Basiswand:Bestand 08.0:161894'},
 {'GlobalId':'3vpWoB_K1EZ8RCaYmNGssv', 'Element':'Fenster 1-flg - Variabel'},
 {'GlobalId':'3vpWoB_K1EZ8RCaYmNGsqI', 'Element':'Fenster 1-flg - Variabel'}
]
```

This could be achieved with the following code in the loop to collect the rows.

```
rows.append({'GlobalId': buildingelement.GlobalId, 'Element': buildingelement.ObjectType})
```